# How can I retrieve a user's public IP address via Amazon API Gateway + Lambda (node)

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm currently writing a Node.js lambda function, in which I want to log the incoming requester's public IP address. I've been looking through both the API Gateway and Lambda docs all day, but haven't found a solution.

Does the lambda `event` object include request metadata I can use to extract the user's IP?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Here is a simple demonstration of using API Gateway's `$context.identity.sourceIp` in a Lambda function.

API Mapping template:

```
{
    "sourceIP" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
}
```

Lambda function:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('SourceIP =', event.identity.sourceIP);
    callback(null, event.identity.sourceIP);
};
```

Comment: This is awesome. Thanks for the mapping info =)

Comment: FYI: For proxy integrations, API Gateway passes entire request through to backend and you do not have any option to modify the passthrough behaviors. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html?shortFooter=true

Comment: For Lambda proxy integrations, the source IP is included in the event passed to the function.
E.g.
event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp

Comment: another question is is it possible to get user-agent too?

Comment: Please note, that if a request goes through a proxy (in my case it was CloudFront), the actual client id will be given in the `X-Forwarded-For` header.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Roman - in my case, I was using an ALB and I also just had `event.multiValueHeaders.x-forwarded-for` not `event.identity.sourceIP`

Answer (score 83):

**Update for HTTP APIs**

Adding @Elijah's comment. The format for HTTP APIs will be

```
event['requestContext']['http']['sourceIp']
```

**Edit**

A better way is actually to check

```
event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']
```

You can also get the User-Agent from the same object

```
event['requestContext']['identity']['userAgent']
```

See Cesar's comment below. Headers are easily spoofed and the user can set `X-Forwarded-For` to anything. AFAIK the `sourceIp` above is retrieved from the TCP connection.

**Original answer**

As of September 2017, you can create a method in API Gateway with Lambda Proxy integration, this will give you access to

```
events['headers']['X-Forwarded-For']
```

Which will look something like `1.1.1.1,214.25.52.1`

The first ip `1.1.1.1` is your user's public ip address.

Comment: This is the real answer, if you are using Lambda proxy integration.  So much easier than adding a mapping for each method.

Comment: Your original answer should be completely removed! The `X-Forwarded-For` header can be spoofed by the user and changed to whatever they want.

Comment: The advice from @Cesar is incomplete: it is true that `X-Forwarded-For` can be set by the client on requests, which makes it important to only use it in cases where you have a trusted proxy and your code only trusts the rightmost value. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: The proxy must be trusted to insert additional IPs to the right of whatever value the client passes in, or even overwrite that value.

Comment: If you're using the new HTTP API instead of REST API it will be event['requestContext']['http']['sourceIp'] instead of event['requestContext']['identity']['sourceIp']

Comment: Thanks @ElijahLofgren I've added that to the answer.

Comment: I am running into this today and sourceIP is only returning the IP for Cloudfront. Maybe X-Forwarded-For can be spoofed, but it is the only reliable way to get the client IP. The tough part is figuring out which IP in the list is correct.

Comment: It should be noted that `event.requestContext.identity` is not present if you're serving a page that's not behind an authorizer.

Answer (score 21):

In the API Gateway, it's the value

```
$context.identity.sourceIp
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html#context-variable-reference

You can pass that through to your Lambda via a mapping template.

Comment: Cool. But, how do I reference the passed through value in my Lambda function?

Comment: I tried doing by mapping template, did almost everything , but that didn't work , Is there any clear step-by-step reference or an example which can talk about it ?

Comment: Apparently this is only true if you are using an "authorizer".in the API Gateway.

Comment: In my case, I was using an ALB, so you have to use `$context.multiValueHeaders.x-forwarded-for` not `$context.identity.sourceIP` - you can also consider the comment of [Roman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7716944/roman-kishchenko) on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

API gateway should already include remote IP in http header `X-Forwarded-For`, so you could:

```js
// Lambda handler function
module.exports.handlerFunc = async (event, context) => {
    // `X-Forwarded-For` should return a comma-delimited list of IPs, first one being remote IP:
    // X-Forwarded-For: '<remote IP>, <cloudfront/API gateway IP>, ...'
    const remoteIp = event.headers['X-Forwarded-For'].split(', ')[0]
    // If you want to see more info available in event and context, add following, deploy and check CloudWatch log:
    // console.log(event, context)
}
```

Comment: Note that this is okay for most use cases, but do NOT use it for allowing/rejecting access to confidential content, because the X-Forwarded-For header can be spoofed, if a malicious user gets their hands on your API Gateway URL and makes the request there directly, skipping CloudFront or whatever you have put on its path. See: https://www.sjoerdlangkemper.nl/2017/03/01/bypass-ip-block-with-x-forwarded-for-header/

Answer (score 2):

```
export const handler = (event) => {
    console.log('ip: ', event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp);
};
```

Comment: this is for nodeJS

Answer (score 0):

I spent a long time trying to figure out how to access this information.

After sifting through a bunch of SO and documentation, I believe you *must* use the ANY method in AWS API Gateway in order for this information to be included in the request, per [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html#:%7E:text=In%20a%20proxy%20integration%2C%20the%20entire%20request%20is%20sent%20to%20the%20backend%20Lambda%20function%20as%2Dis%2C%20via%20a%20catch%2Dall%20ANY%20method%20that%20represents%20any%20HTTP%20method.)

Additionally, you'll need to configure the api gateway resource to function as a proxy integration endpoint (check the link provided above).

Then you should be able to find what you are looking for using the following sytax (at least for Node)
`requestContext = event?.requestContext`

Answer (score -1):

```
exports.handler = (event, context) => {
    console.log('ip:', event.headers["x-forwarded-for"].split(",")[0].trim());
};
```