# Is there anyway to automate assigning new IP address to security groups in inbound rules with lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ip-address

We should be able to add the IP address to inbound rules when an API gateway is triggered and the added IP address needs to be deleted after a particular defined time from the security group. Is there any way to automate this process using aws lambda

Comment: But which IP address do you want to add?

Comment: the ip address is obtained from client when an API gateway is triggered..then ill have to use the trigger to inturn trigger a Lambda Python script which adds the IP address on Port 90 in inbound rules which needs to be deleted automatically within a given time frame

Answer (score 0):

I think so.

- Trigger a lambda function when a API gateway is called. Pass the required arguments to lambda. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-with-lambda-integration.html
- In the lambda, modify your security group. Keep security in mind here, since you're using user input to modify your infrastructure.
- Still in the lambda, schedule another lambda to be run after some time. You can do this with CloudWatch: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html (this lambda should have enough info to identify which rule to remove from which SG)
- When the scheduled lambda runs, it should remove the rule from the Security Group.

Comment: `sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='183.82.107.236/32',FromPort(90),ToPort(90),IpProtocol = 'tcp')                                                   
  File "<ipython-input-21-6ddf412a24b6>", line 1
    sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='183.82.107.236/32',FromPort(90),ToPort(90),IpProtocol = 'tcp')
                                                   ^
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` . Hey man i was wondering if you can also assist me with the code and tell me the cause of this error

Comment: `sg.authorize_ingress(CidrIp='183.82.107.236/32',FromPort(90),ToPort(90),IpProtocol = 'tcp')` You can't have positional arguments (`FormPort(90)`) after Keyword arguments (`CidrIp=...`)

Comment: Ohh yea i got it ....started working on the steps ..Thankyou for the suggestions .

Comment: How can my script locate the IP address of device from where the API or URL is triggered ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062097/how-can-i-retrieve-a-users-public-ip-address-via-amazon-api-gateway-lambda-n

Comment: `'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('SourceIP =', event.sourceIP);
    callback(null, event.sourceIP);
}; ` . Please tell if i understand this ..the ip address is now stored in the event,sourceIP and i can directly pass it to CidrIp  like wise `CidrIp = event.sourceIP` ?