# How to Get User's public IP from AWS API Gateway cloudwatch Logs?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to get users' public IP address logged to CloudWatch logs in AWS API Gateway.

I created a Model named  SourceIP and tried to add the following schema as per the AWS offical docs, but it gives me errors.

Code :

```
{
     "source_ip" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
    
}
```

Error :

> Invalid model specified: Validation Result: warnings : [], errors :
> [Invalid model schema specified. Unsupported keyword(s):
> ["source_ip"]]

What may be the issue on my schema ?

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you integrating the lambda with  API Gateway? For Lambda proxy integrations, the source IP is included in the event passed to the function. E.g. event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp. [Integration passthrough behaviors](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/integration-passthrough-behaviors.html?shortFooter=true). You can checkout this post [How can I retrieve a user's public IP address via Amazon API Gateway + Lambda (node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062097/how-can-i-retrieve-a-users-public-ip-address-via-amazon-api-gateway-lambda-n)

Comment: @samtoddler I'm using lambda proxy integration with API Gateway

Comment: In that case , API Gateway passes the entire request through to your backend. If you wanna log the. You can actually log. the requests  [How do I enable CloudWatch Logs for troubleshooting my API Gateway REST API or WebSocket API?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/)

Comment: @samtoddler I'm looking to log source IP in CloudWatch, but how can it be done ?

Comment: I added detailed steps in the answer.

Comment: @samtoddler do you have any idea why I get above Error in the description I've added. That's the error I get.

Comment: Mapping template overrides cannot be used with proxy integration endpoints, which lack data mappings and `mapping templates` and `models` are two different things. If you are not using `proxy` integration then you can add the mappings by going to `method ->integration -> at the bottom Mapping Template`

Comment: @samtoddler thanks for your detail description in the answer and it helped me a lot..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Use a mapping template to override an API's request and response parameters and status codes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-override-request-response-parameters.html)

> Mapping template overrides cannot be used with proxy integration endpoints, which lack data mappings

- Models are only for representing input and output formats
- Mapping templates for transforming data

You can enable the logging in API gateway by following the steps:

1. Create an IAM with `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonAPIGatewayPushToCloudWatchLogs` permissions attached and following trust policy

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "apigateway.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

2. Set this IAM role in the

```
- In the API Gateway console, on the APIs pane, choose the name of an API that you created.
- In the left navigation pane, at the bottom, choose Settings.
- Under Settings, for CloudWatch log role ARN, paste the IAM role ARN that you copied.
- Choose Save.
```

Now there are two methods for logging the IP address

- Go to your AWS API Gateway instance within the AWS Console. Select Stages on the left menu and then select the Logs/Tracing tab Toggle on `Enable CloudWatch Logs` and select `Log Level` as `INFO`

and then

You can enable the mapping template by going [image]

which results in the access logs like:

[image]

On top of this you can see the ip address in the `Method request headers` as well

```
(b1fe0021-8064-4be8-a548-203c6fd795a6) Method request headers: 

{accept-language=en-us, User-Agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0.3 Safari/605.1.15, 
X-Forwarded-Proto=https, 
X-Forwarded-For=8.xx.xx.xx, 
Host=xxxxx.execute-api.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com, 
X-Forwarded-Port=443, accept-encoding=gzip, deflate, br,
X-Amzn-Trace-Id=Root=1-602e74b0-439e58b379ac537c27664a34, accept=text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8}
```

If you don't enable the `CloudWatch` Loggin this information for the `IP` address via the mapping template will be passed to the endpoint as well.
Like descirbed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37560348/2246345), for example lambda.

```json
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('SourceIP =', event.identity.sourceIP);
    callback(null, event.identity.sourceIP);
};
```

OR

- Go to your AWS API Gateway instance within the AWS Console. Select Stages on the left menu and then select the Logs/Tracing tab Toggle on Enable Access Logging and add your cloudwatch log group where you want to log.

  - Add the JSON log , I added few more along with IP address.

```json
{   
    "ip": "$context.identity.sourceIp", 
    "apiId": "$context.apiId",
    "requestId": "$context.requestId", 
    "requestTime": "$context.requestTime", 
    "protocol": "$context.protocol", 
...

...
}
```

- Click Save Changes and that’s it! API logs should start showing up after a few minutes.

[image]

[How do I enable CloudWatch Logs for troubleshooting my API Gateway REST API or WebSocket API?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/)