# error deploying lambda and api gateway to get client IP

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

attempting to learn aws lambda and api gateway.
Attempting  to recreate http://checkip.amazonaws.com/ (returns client's public IP).

I found - [How can I retrieve a user's public IP address via Amazon API Gateway + Lambda (node)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33062097/how-can-i-retrieve-a-users-public-ip-address-via-amazon-api-gateway-lambda-n) .

It says -
API Mapping template:

```
{
    "sourceIP" : "$context.identity.sourceIp"
}
```

Lambda function:

```
'use strict';
console.log('Loading function');
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log('SourceIP =', event.identity.sourceIP);
    callback(null, event.identity.sourceIP);
};
```

Not sure what I'm doing incorrectly. In AWS console, I -
select "create function"
select "author from scratch"
Enter my function's name and choose Node.js 14.X runtime.
I click on "create function" and add the function code.

I then -
Navigate to api gateway
click on "build" under "Rest API"
I select "New API"
I name it, give it a description and slick on "create api"
I create the "Get" method with lambda integration type, select the lambda I created earlier, and click "Save".
I then click on the "Integration Request", select "Mapping Templates", add application/json as the content type, and the mapping template.

after saving, I deploy the API.
When I try a "Get" on the invoke URL, the response I get is -

```
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'sourceIP' of undefined",
    "trace": [
        "TypeError: Cannot read property 'sourceIP' of undefined",
        "    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/index.js:4:46)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

Thanks for any help in resolving this error or clearly explaining / showing screenshots of any better ways to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: The source IP is under `event.requestContext.identity.sourceIp` for v1 of the API Gateway interface, and `event.requestContext.http.sourceIp` for v2.  See the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-develop-integrations-lambda.html)

Comment: You can also simply console.log the `event` and `context` parameters to review what's contained in them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Not familiar with how to do this, but will research it.

Comment: console.log(event/context);